# Raising an integer to the Xth power

Tags: c++, function, loops, exponentiation

In response to this prompt:

> Write a function `integerPower( base, exponent )` that returns the value of base exponent. For example, `integerPower( 3, 4 ) == 3 * 3 * 3 * 3`. Assume that `exponent` is a positive, nonzero integer and `base` is an integer. The function `integerPower` should use `for` or `while` to control the calculation. Do not use any math library functions.

I wrote this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int integer (int a, int b) {
  int e;

  for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++)
    e *= a;

  return (e);
}

int main () {
  cout << "enter number and exponent";
  cin >> num >> exp;
  cout << num << "to the power" << exp << "is" <<;
  int num, exp, n;
  integer (num, exp, n);
  getch ();
  return 0;
}
```

For some reason the function `integer (int a, int b)` returns 0 no matter what the values of `a` and `b` are. Why?

Comment: Hint: zero times anything, (except maybe infinity), is still zero!

Comment: @Martin zero times infinity is maths undefined behaviour `;-)`

Comment: ***PLEASE*** do **NOT** use `exp` as a variable name. Especially if you are `abusing namespace std;` (which you shouldn't in fact be using, but anyway.) It's the name of a math library function.

Comment: @H2CO3: hey, the assignment instructions say not to use any math library functions. What better way to avoid that than shadowing their names? ;-)

Comment: No one has mentioned that you're calling the function with too many arguments.

Comment: @SteveJessop Fair enough :D

Answer (score 3):

You should Initialize e to 1.

```
int e = 1;
```

Also, you are not declaring the type of `num` and `exp` at the correct place.

```
int main () {
  cout << "enter number and exponent";
  int num, exp;
  cin >> num >> exp;
  cout << num << "to the power" << exp << "is" << integer (num, exp); // remove the third parameter
  getch ();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function `integer`, initialize `e` like this :

```
int e = 1;
```

Also, move `int num, exp, n;` before the `cin` statement.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in other answers, you must declare num and exp variables in main function, and initialize e to 1 in function integer. But you don't need to use the namespace std, you simply add std:: to the reference of its members, like std::cin, std::cout and your code will be more clear yet. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is not clear why the exponent equal to 0 was excluded as an acceptable value. I would write the function the following way

```
int integerPower( int base, unsigned int exponent )
{
   int result = 1;

   while ( exponent-- != 0 ) result *= base;

   return ( result );
}
```